# Docker has considerable different execution time on machines with same configuration

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm running **Docker** on Windows 10 Pro (Docker Toolbox installation) on 3 different machines, but with the same configuration: 16Gb RAM, SSD, Core i7 and so on. Apart from that, the versions are the same for:

- Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
- Docker-machine.exe version 0.12.2, build 9371605
- docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e3

All docker commands perform better in one of them - but it is a **considerable** difference. To gather some metrics, I've executed some commands making use of Powershell's `Measure-Command`.
Here, some examples:

```
Measure-Command {docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 9500 --virtualbox-cpu-count 4 --virtualbox-host-dns-resolver my-tests}
```

Machine 1 results (*I omitted not needed info to facilitate the reading*):

```
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 11
Milliseconds      : 649
```

Machine 2 results:

```
Minutes           : 2
Seconds           : 01
Milliseconds      : 465
```

Machine 3 results:

```
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 59
Milliseconds      : 166
```

---

```
PS C:\dev\ > Measure-Command {docker cp ./dist/exploded {CONTAINER_ID}:/opt/jboss/server/deploy}
```

Machine 1:

```
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 6
Milliseconds      : 162
```

Machine 2:

```
Minutes           : 4
Seconds           : 32
Milliseconds      : 900
```

Machine 3:

```
Minutes           : 4
Seconds           : 40
Milliseconds      : 945
```

The same pattern repeats for all docker operations: cp, start, restart and, as the containers are JBoss / Elastic Search and MySQL, therefore, every request presents a delay when invoking on machine 2 or 3 (in comparison to the machine 1).

As you probably must have realized, I'm using the VirtualBox as machine driver to Docker and the VirtualBox versions is the same for every environment - Version 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.2).

Has anyone noticed some strange behavior like this before?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you try using hyperV instead of virtualbox ?

Comment: To me Windows does not seem to be the natural environment for doing this. BTW, is it really always the same machine that performs best, or does it depend on the order the machines have been started?

Comment: @aventurin I totally agree with your comment (all the other times that I handled docker containers in Linux environment I had a good performance at all), but it isn't an option that I can manage now - corporative stuff. Besides, yes, it is always the same machine that performs best.

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron I tried, nonetheless, it was heavily consuming memory in all machines (the 3 aforementioned). The proportion was something like: while in virtualbox we had 6 containers using about 10Gb [OS and other programs sharing this], the hyperv with 4 containers was reaching 15Gb - with absolutely nothing different virtualbox, I can ensure.